# Reading data from specific COM port

Tags: c#

I want to Know how to read data from specific `COM PORT` like COM port 6 in c#
here is the code how i am reading but cant find how to access the port

```
var port = new SerialPort();
port.PortName = "COM";
port.BaudRate = 9600;
port.Parity = Parity.None;
port.DataBits = 8;
port.StopBits = StopBits.One;
```

Comment: @PaulMcCowat post is empty

Comment: It didn't format the link properly, I've added as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you want port 6, you need

```
port.PortName = "COM6".
```

Also look at [this post](http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx).